# I am getting Error when I developing a chart in Next JS application using react chart js

Tags: next.js, react-chartjs-2

The error:

> Failed to compile ./app/Components/Barchart.jsx ReactServerComponentsError:  You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server components by default.    1 | import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';    :                           ^^^^^^^^^  2 | import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';  3 | import {  4 |   Chart as ChartJS,    `----  Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":   ./app/Components/Barchart.jsx   ./app/page.js This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.

Why is it appearing when I'm trying to develop like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

const BarChart = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    datasets: [],
  });

  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setChartData({
        labels: ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Sales $',
                data: [18127, 22201, 19490, 17938, 24182, 17842, 22475],
                borderColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235, 0.4',
              }, 
        ]
    })
    setChartOptions({
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Daily Revenue'
            }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div className='w-full md:col-span-2 relative lg:h-[70vh] h-[50vh] m-auto p-4 border rounded-lg bg-white'>
        <Bar data={chartData} options={chartOptions} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

I am using chartjs to make a bar chart in my next app but I am getting an error in the browser. So how do I prevent it and what is the reason for that.
I am using the latest Nextjs version and and I got the chart dependencies from this link https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/

Comment: I put that one also but I am getting same error